# differential forms and orientation in Bott and Tu

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-forms

I am reading Bott and Tu book on my own. If you have the text you can answer my question perhaps, if not it would be too long to explain it.

I have gotten to page 29. I am confused about proposition 3.2 and the way a differential form is defined on page 21. They define it  as a collection of forms $\omega_U$ which produce the same pullback on intersection of charts. Essentially they identify the differential forms  on open charts with $R^n$ which can be made compatible nothing more. If you read the text you see on page 29, proposition 3.2, they show the pull back of the standard $n$ form $R^n$. I don't see why the existence of positive global form from their definition implies there is a positive $f_\alpha$ and also how the same thing would work in opposite direction for $\Phi_\alpha^{-1}$ ?  Explaining that paragraph generally would be helpful. thanks.

Comment: That's because the space of $n$-form is one dimensional. So if you have two nonzero $n$-form on $U$ ($\phi^*_\alpha dx_1 \cdots dx_n$ and $w$), then at each point $x \in U$ they must differ by a nonzero constant $f_\alpha(x)$.

Comment: @John need not be non vanishing

Comment: @alirena: Don't quite understand your comment. Do you mean you think $f_\alpha(x)$ might be zero at some $x\in U$?

Comment: @john it could be yes, for example if the manifold is not orient-able it would be.

Comment: if the manifold is not orientable, such a $w$ does not exists.

Comment: @john I know these things from other books and approaches I want to see how it follows from Butt and Tu construction.